# sqlite data access concept

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been reading about sqlite and am a bit confused: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

If the db is stored on your device and is private to the app you subclassed sqlliteopenhelper in, how would someone else access data you insert without a common server?

And if it's stored in the filesystem, why do I keep hearing that it's an "in-memory" database?  It exists even when your app has exited and can be retrieved once the app restarts.

Comment: sharedpreferences provides key value persistence that is available to any app on your device, so that's another difference.  The main diffs I see are that sqllite provies relationships between the data and sharedpres is not private to an app.

Comment: `sqlite is just a structured version of sharedpreferences.` **!!!** I think you know little or nothing about databases...

Comment: instead of trolling answer my specific questions, db offer relationships like one to many, many to many etc, I was surprised and confused about the non server aspect of it.

Comment: SQLite on Android id for **local** dbs. If you want an online db (i.e.: a shared one), use a webservice, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases indeed are private.
If you want to give other apps access to your data, you have to create a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), which works somewhat like a server.

A database stored in a file is not an in-memory database.
Wherever you have heard this, it's not on the page you linked to.

Comment: I've been hearing about it from other people, but it went against what I read about sqllite storing records in a structured file on disk.  It looks like that is indeed an inaccurate statement, and is only an option in sqlite if there isn't a need to persist data beyond the application lifecycle.